# performance issues using UNION , multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

Union in the oracle query is causing a lot of FTS (full table scans) and high row count any better way i can rewrite this query ?

performance issues using UNION

```
    SELECT
                    store.store_name name,
                    store.block_id block_id,
                    store.marker flag,
                    substr('A',1,1) store_type,
                    substr(area.area_code,1,5) area_code,
                    substr(area.area_name,1,5) area_name
    FROM  store , area
            where store.store_id = area.store_id
            and store.block_id = area.block_id
    UNION
     SELECT
                    store.store_name name,
                    store.block_id block_id,
                    store.marker flag,
                    substr('A',1,1) store_type,
                    substr(market.market_code,1,5) area_code,
                    substr(market.market_area,1,5) area_name
    FROM  store , market
            where store.store_id = market.store_id 
            and store.block_id =market.block_id;                                

                 | Id  | Operation                     | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |  1845K|    61M|       |   120K  (1)| 00:00:05 |
                 |   1 |  UNION-ALL                    |       |       |       |            |          |
                 |   2 |   MERGE JOIN                  |  1719K|    57M|       | 98522   (2)| 00:00:04 |
                 |   3 |    SORT JOIN                  |  1761K|    25M|    94M| 30984   (1)| 00:00:02 |
                 |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         |  1761K|    25M|       | 21911   (1)| 00:00:01 |
                 |*  5 |    SORT JOIN                  |  1882K|    35M|   115M| 67538   (2)| 00:00:03 |
                 |   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         |  1882K|    35M|       | 56061   (2)| 00:00:03 |
                 |   7 |   NESTED LOOPS                |   126K|  3699K|       | 22186   (1)| 00:00:01 |
                 |   8 |    NESTED LOOPS               |   126K|  3699K|       | 22186   (1)| 00:00:01 |
                 |   9 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         |   126K|  1726K|       |  3232   (2)| 00:00:01 |
```

Index are on (tab1 (aid,bid), tab2(aid,bid) , tab3(cid,bid))

Comment: To start with: the query seems kind of strange. A table should represent some entity, say users, employees, departments, movies, whatever. So tab2 and tab3 representing different entities, why would you glue the results together? Maybe you should be less abstract here and tell us what the tables contain, then we might be able to suggest changes. As is, the query is okay and cannot really be optimized.

Comment: Do you need `UNION`'s duplicate elimination, or can you instead do `UNION ALL`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner updating the query

Comment: @jarlh  i need the duplicate elimination too

Comment: `substr('A',1,1)` is `'A'`. And if you are interested in substrings (e.g. `substr(area.area_code,1,5)`), this indicates that you should better store string parts in separate columns. What do the first five characters in an area code, an area name, a market code and a market name represent?

Comment: What are the table's primary keys? I suppose for `store` it's `store_id`? But what is a `block_id` then?

Comment: Have you tried building covering indexes? I mean index on `Store` on columns `store`, `block_id` and `marker` etc.

Comment: Edit your post again - make the last line to agree with your other changes. What are `tab1`, `aid` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, UNION will not cause the FTS.  FTS is decided by the optimizer if it thinks it can do better scanning all the rows rather than an indexed access followed by a table access.  So I see a few issues with this problem as posed:

1. there is no data subsetting, which means you want all the rows
   anyway, so if that is the case, then FTS is likely going to be the
   lowest cost option.
2. with no data subsetting, the only possible way for an index to be
   used is if the "join columns" are indexes in at least the table that
   follows the FTS (in some cases you might look for the smaller table
   to be FTS, followed by indexed access to the larger table based on
   the join condition column being indexes).
3. you don't indicate the table sizes or what the indexes are;
   knowledge of the cardinality etc. is essential to SQL tuning.

Also, if you have license to Diagnostics+Tuning Pack, you can run the SQL through the SQL Tuning Advisor and see what tuning advice this tool provides.